# Encoding the first element of an ordered pair

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming we are working in axiomatic set theory, such as $ZFC$ or $NBG$ can we, for all ordered pairs $(x, y)$ find a function, call it $First$ such that $First((x, y))=x$ Is such a thing possible if we are using Kuratowski's definition of the ordered pair, namely $(x, y) = \{ \{x \}, \{ x, y \} \}$.
One thing that comes to mind is to take $First(t)=\bigcup\bigcap t$
Can we also generalize this? Like assuming an $n$-ordered tuple, call it y, can we define a predicate $P(y, m)$ such that it gives us the $m$-th component of $y$.

One way I thought about doing this is to completely disregard the Kuratowski definition and identify an $n$-ordered tuple as a function with its domain $n$, where as a set $n= \{ 0, 1, ..., n - 1 \}$. Therefore, my predicate $P(y, m)$ is nothing but $y(m)$ with the assumption that $y$ is a function. This generalization would work for ordered tuples with  arbitrary length, even infinite.

I feel like what I have done is cheating, so I am wondering if we can find a function $P(y, m)$ without appealing to the concept of functions and defining an ordered tuple with a Kuratowski-like definition or Wiener's definition.

Comment: For what it's worth, $\bigcup\bigcap t$ does not depend on any special properties of the two components. If $t=(a,b)$, then $\bigcap t=\{\,z\in\bigcup t\mid \forall u\in t\colon z\in u\,\}=\{a\}\cap \{a,b\}=\{a\}$, no matter what $b$ is (and $\bigcup\{a\}=a$). -- Then clearly $Second(t)=\bigcup \{\,z\in\bigcup t\mid t=\{First(t),\{First(t),z\}\}\,\}$

Comment: This is the projection map, $\pi_1$. The wikipedia article on ordered pairs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair, gives a (rather complicated) expression for $\pi_2$.. What about $\pi_n$ though?

Comment: If you're going to “identify an $n$-ordered tuple as a function with domain $\{0\ldots n-1\}$”, you need to have a special case for $n=2$ because a function is by definition a set of $2$-tuples.

Comment: You may be interested in [this blog article](https://blog.plover.com/math/wiener-pairs-2.html) which discusses the projection formulas for the Kuratowski pair and then observes that the corresponding formulas for the (historically earlier) Wiener pair are much simpler. This suggests that it might be easier to generalize the Wiener pair to $n$-tuples. Getting the second component of the Kuratowski pair is quite a pain.

Comment: @MJD can't we identify pairs with functions with domain $\{ 0, 1, ..., n-1  \}$ even for $n=2$? We can take the Kuratowski definition or Weiner definition to define functions and make sure they are founded, they completly give up on using them and just using functions whenever we are talking about ordered pairs? Like it seems much more convenient to use Kuratowski and/or Weiner to have the functions well defined and then defining the standard ordered paris as plain functions and for convenienve make them have as a domain an ordinal/cardinal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to first answer your main question:

> can we, for all ordered pairs $(x, y)$ find a monadic predicate, call it $\def\Fst{{\rm First}}\Fst$ such that $\Fst((x, y))=x$?

And the answer is, yes, absolutely.  If someone put forth some notion of ordered pairs, and there was *not* some way of extracting the $x$ from $(x, y)$, we would tell them to go away and come back when they had something useful.  So yes,  we  can do this with Kuratowski pairs.  You can find the formulas [in the Wikipedia article on “ordered pair”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski%27s_definition).  As you surmised, $\Fst(p)$ is just $\bigcup\bigcap p$.  The corresponding ${\rm Second}(p)$ is unfortunately rather more complicated.

---

But you should know there is nothing really special about the Kuratowski formula $$(x, y) = \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}.$$  It was not the first or only set-theoretic model of ordered pairs.  It was preceded historically by Norbert Wiener's definition:

$$(x, y) = \{\{\{x\},\emptyset\}, \{\{y\}\}\}$$

and by Felix Hausdorff's:

$$(x, y) = \{\{1, x\}, \{2, y\}\}$$

which incidentally looks rather a lot like what you wanted to do:

> identify an $$-ordered tuple as a function …with its domain $\{0,1,...,−1\}$.

Hausdorff's pair *isn't* a function with domain $\{1, 2\}$, but it almost looks like one, and Hausdorff's motivation was probably similar to yours.  It's a very natural idea!

But there's an important technical problem with your suggestion to represent an $n$-tuple as a function.  The problem is that in set theory, functions are usually modeled as sets of pairs.  The function $$\begin{array}{rl}
1\to&\text{Fish} \\
2\to&\text{Carrot} \\
\end{array}$$

is usually understood as being equal to the set

$$\{(1, \text{Fish}),
(2, \text{Carrot})\}$$

Where the $(x, y)$ expressions are ordered pairs.  So you have to have pairs *before* you have functions. If you want the ordered pairs to *also* be functions, you are stuck in a loop: you have defined ordered pairs as functions, but defined functions as sets of ordered pairs.

To make your idea work you would need to to find some way of defining what a function is without using ordered pairs, or you would need to make an exception for pairs, and posit that $n$-tuples should be functions when $n>2$, but are Kuratowski sets (or whatever) when $n=2$.

---

But now I come to the real point:

> The specific definition of an ordered $n$-tuple, as a particular set, is not of very much importance.

Kuratowski's definition is most often used because in some ways it is simplest; certainly it is easy to write down.  But there is nothing special about it. Notice that $(x, y) = \{\{y\}, \{x, y\}\}$  would clearly work just as well as the usual $(x,y) = \{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$.

What *is* important in set theory is only that there be *some* method for representing the pair $(x, y)$ as a set so that these three properties hold:

1. $(a,b) = (c,d)$ if and only if $a=c$ and $b=d$
2. We can find a formula $\text{First}$ so that $\text{First}((x,y)) = x$
3. We can find a formula $\text{Second}$ so that $\text{Second}((x,y)) = y$

Kuratowski's definition satisfies these requirements, and so do Wiener's and Hausdorff's and many others.  Once we've proved that the three properties hold, we usually forget about the internal details of exactly what set is meant by $(x, y)$.  Wiener's original paper says “the particular method selected of doing this is largely a matter of choice”. As long as there is *some* set that behaves the way we want the pair $(x, y)$ to behave, we don't actually care very much what that set is.

Here's how it was put by [J.H. Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway), a famous mathematician, who seemed rather frustrated by the insistence that every entity in his theory be representable as some specific set in ZF:

> It seems to us, however, that mathematics has reached the stage where formalization within some particular axiomatic theory is irrelevant… It should be possible to specify conditions on a mathematical theory which would suffice for embeddability within ZF but which do not otherwise restrict the possible constructions in that theory. … Among the permissible kinds of construction we should have:
>
> 1. Objects may be created from earlier objects in any reasonably constructive fashion.
> 2. Equality among the created objects can be any desired equivalence relation.
>
> … We could, for instance, freely create a new object $(x, y)$ and call it the ordered pair of $x$ and $y$. We could also create an ordered pair $[x, y]$ different from $(x, y)$ but co-existing with it, and neither of these need have any relation to the set $\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$.

(J.H. Conway, [*On Numbers and Games*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Numbers_and_Games), 2 ed. (2001) p.66)

Finally, I would like to note that the basic philosophy of the extremely successful branch of mathematics called *category theory* is that these internal details matter so little that one can—and should—forget about them entirely!

In category theory, one says that a set (or other object) $C$ “is [a product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) of $A$ and $B$”, meaning that it is something like the set of pairs of elements of $A$ and $B$. This  object $C$ is considered to be such a product if two required functions $$\text{First} : C\to A\\\text{Second} : C\to B$$ exist and have certain properties that I won't go into. Whether $C$ is a set of Kuratowski pairs or Wiener pairs or something else is of absolutely no interest in category theory, so long as we can identify satisfactory $\text{First}$ and $\text{Second}$. The phrasing “$C$ is **a** product of $A$ and $B$” rather than “$C$ is **the** product of $A$ and $B$” is intended to emphasize this.

Category theory is successful precisely because it ignores the unimportant details of what is going on inside the particular project object. If it has a suitable $\text{First}$ and $\text{Second}$, that is good enough.  (Category theorists usually call these $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$, but the idea is exactly the same.)

Well, that is probably far more than you wanted to know.

---

(By the way, you are using the term “predicate” incorrectly. A predicate function is one that yields true or false.  For example, “$x$ is an even number” is an example of a predicate, and so is “The first component of the pair $p$ is equal to $7$”.  But “The first component of the pair $p$” is **not** a predicate.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, regarding the definition of ordered pairs. Can't we define functions in terms of Kuratowski/Wiener/whatever definition of ordered paris, and then define ordered tuples? Like use Kuratowski/Wiener/whatever defintion just to define functions, then completly abandon the definiton and have pairs as function with domain the set $2$. From what you have answered, I think the answer is yes, but again not of importance. I think the definition of functions as tuples would make the canonical projections $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ much more easy to write

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ is defined recursively as $((x_1,x_2,...x_{n-1}),x_n)$. To get the $m^{th}$ coordinate note that:
$(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=((x_1,x_2,...x_{n-1}),x_n)=(((x_1,x_2,...x_{n-2}),x_{n-1}),x_n) =(((..(x_1,x_2,...x_{m-1}),x_m),x_{m+1})...x_n) $.
And so the $m^{th}$ co-ordnate is $\pi_2(\pi_1(...(\pi_1((x_1,x_2,...x_n)))...)$ where the $\pi_1$ is repreated $n-m$ times.We know the expression for $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ so we have an expression for $\pi_m$.

Comment: This would work if we interpret the set necessarily as a $n$-ordered pair, which is not possible with Kuratowski's definition. For example a $3$-ordered pair, with Kuratowski is defined as $((a, b), c) = \{ \{ \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}\}, \{ \{ \{a\}, \{a, b\}\}, c\}\}$. However if you take $a=b$ you get $((a, a), c) = \{ \{ \{ \{a\}\}\}, \{\{\{a\}\}, c\}\}$ which can be interpreted as a tuple $(\{\{a\}\}, c)$ because they are equal as sets, but we don't want to allow such things. And applying $\pi_1$or$\pi_2$ would be problematic on pairs that don't have the appropiate structure

Comment: I believe that your concern is with my definition of n-tuple in that it has the property, for example, that $((a,a),c)=(\{a\},c)$ But it is one possible definition, refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13031/how-to-define-tuples. The important thing is it has the property that if $(a,b,c)=(d,e,f)$ then $a=d,b=e$ and $c=f$, as mentioned here : https://mathoverflow.net/a/13042. The definition I have used does have this property. If you don't like this defintion, which one do you want to use?

Comment: I have realized that I phrased my question wrong. The definition you proposed does indeed have the defining property of a tuple, the only problem the Kuratowski definition has is that a set can be interpreted at the same time as a $2$-ordered pair and as a $3$-ordered tuple. My concern was also to have a function that would output the $m$-th element of a tuple $y$(possible infinite length) such that $P(y, m)$=$m$-th element. The function works as intended only if we make the convention to interpret a set as a $n$-th ordered tuple.

Comment: In your definition of $P(y, m)$ you also include $n$ to apply $\pi$ $n-m$ times, however this relies on the convention that all the sets are interpreted as $n$-ordered Kuratowski tuples. First let's assume that $y$ is an ordered pair of length $n$(possibly infinite). What I would be looking for is a function $P(y, m)$ such that it would give me the $m$-th component of $y$ regardless of the length of $y$ and possibly output the empty set if $m$ "is greater" than the length of $y$.

Comment: I don't know how I should phrase my question without making it look too complicated and still making my point clear, I guess that is a question for meta stack exchange.

Comment: Are you aware of generalised Cartesian products, https://planetmath.org/generalizedcartesianproduct. Maybe this is what you are getting at?